# Tensorflow.js => TypeError: response.arrayBuffer is not a function

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, tensorflow.js

I have a bot that uses tensorflow.js and runs non-stop using a `setInterval()`. When I run the bot one time and `control + c`, everything works properly. When I let the bot running, this error logs: `TypeError: response.arrayBuffer is not a function`.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
"@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.7.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.7.4",
```

Here's how I initialise these packages:

```
// tensorflow;
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Here's how I use tensorflow.js in my cde:

```
const readImage = path => {
  const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync("img/actual.jpg");
  const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
  return tfimage;
};

const imageClassification = async path => {
  const image = readImage(path);
  const mobilenetModel = await mobilenet.load();
  const predictions = await mobilenetModel.classify(image);
  outputData.predictions = predictions;
  return translatePrediction(predictions);
};
```

Here's the simple `setInterval()` I'm using:

```
let tweetInterval = Math.round(
  Math.random() * (3000 - 4000)
) + 4000;

setInterval(function() {
  runTheBot()
}, tweetInterval);
```

My code is available here: https://github.com/cyruslk/debord_slow_sender_meme/tree/without_meme

Comment: Please, could you add relevant part of the code direclty in the question ?

Comment: The fact is that I have no ideas what the relevant part of the code since it does not produce the error when the code runs one time, but let me edit with the part of the code where I'm using tensorflow.js

Comment: Unless you can really narrow down your problem to the specific code causing the issue, I don't see how the code here can help

Comment: That is why I have not added it initially, I really do not know what is going on here.